# Ich arbeite als Arzt an/in/bei der Klinik?

Tags: preposition

Sagt man

- > Ich arbeite als Oberarzt auf der Klinik für Traumatologie

oder

- > Ich arbeite als Oberarzt in der Klinik für Traumatologie

oder

- > Ich arbeite als Oberarzt bei der Klinik für Traumatologie

oder

- > Ich arbeite als Oberarzt an der Klinik für Traumatologie

Ich tendiere für die letzte Variante aber da ich schweizerdeutsch rede, vertraue ich meinem Ohr nicht... 
Vielen Dank im Voraus.

Comment: Ich tendiere zu *in der Klinik* (ist ja nie falsch, denn er arbeitet ja wohl drinnen) order *an der Klinik* (ähnlich wie "ich lehre am Gymnasium").

Comment: Danke Rudy für dein Input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich arbeite als Oberarzt an der Klinik für Traumatologie.

Für den Arbeitsplatz/die Art der Arbeit.

> Ich arbeite als Oberarzt in der Klinik für Traumatologie.

Ortsbeschreibung.

> Ich arbeite als Oberarzt bei der Klinik für Traumatologie.

Beschreibung des Arbeitgebers. Eher mit Eigennamen.

> Ich arbeite als Oberarzt auf der Station für Traumatologie.

*Klinik* passt hier nicht.

---

> Ich arbeite als Oberarzt auf der Station für Hals- und Beinbruch bei Rhön an der Klinik für Traumatologie in Bad Bramstedt.

Comment: "*Klinik* passt hier nicht." es sei denn, er arbeitet auf dem Dach. <g>